# DevEx TreeList Two editors in one column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I'm using DevExpress 8 Winform TreeList control for my UI,
I need my first column to be 2 editors at once:
One is the default TextEdit,
The other is a check box..

I tried to search for this in the DevEx forums but all I found was
a suggestion to implement a custom edit to contain both edits..

I'm not a UI person, but is this really the way to go?
Is there any other way to fuse two edits together in one column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  To show several editors in the same cell, you should implement a custom editor which will contain required editors inside.